# Add function into class by using foreach glob

Tags: php, powershell, class

Right now i am using

```
foreach (glob("app/view/components/*/*.php") as $filename) {
  require_once $filename;
}
```

so there is automatically pick up every component as a function basically, but i like to use in Class so i can use like that:

```
Component::input($x);
```

but can't do that in class, if i do that

```
class Component{
  foreach (glob("app/view/components/*/*.php") as $filename) {
    require_once $filename;
  }
}
```

I hope somebody help me i am currently using function. Please suggest some way to add function into a single class.

I used PowerShell and php script because not good enough in PowerShell

```
$Path =$PSScriptRoot;
$FileFilter = '*.php'  
$IncludeSubfolders = $true
$AttributeFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName, [IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite 
try
{
  $watcher = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property @{
    Path = $Path
    Filter = $FileFilter
    IncludeSubdirectories = $IncludeSubfolders
    NotifyFilter = $AttributeFilter
  }
  $action = {
    $details = $event.SourceEventArgs
    $Name = $details.Name
    $FullPath = $details.FullPath
    $OldFullPath = $details.OldFullPath
    $OldName = $details.OldName
    $ChangeType = $details.ChangeType
    $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
    $global:all = $details
    php C:\xampp816\htdocs\intaxingnew\php\app\view\components\compile.php
    $text = "{0} was {1} at ford {2}" -f $FullPath, $ChangeType, $Timestamp
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host $text -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
  switch ($ChangeType)
    {
      'Changed'  { "CHANGE" }
      'Created'  { "CREATED"}
      'Deleted'  { "DELETED"
        Write-Host "Deletion Handler Start" -ForegroundColor Gray
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 4    
        Write-Host "Deletion Handler End" -ForegroundColor Gray
      }
      'Renamed'  { 
        $text = "File {0} was renamed to {1}" -f $OldName, $Name
        Write-Host $text -ForegroundColor Yellow
      }
      default   { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor White }
    }
  }
  $handlers = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Changed  -Action $action 
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created  -Action $action 
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Deleted  -Action $action 
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Renamed  -Action $action 
  }
 $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

  Write-Host "Watching for changes to $Path"
 do
  {
    Wait-Event -Timeout 1
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
  } while ($true)
}
finally
{
  $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
  $handlers | ForEach-Object {
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $_.Name
  }
  $handlers | Remove-Job
  $watcher.Dispose()  
  Write-Warning "Event Handler disabled, monitoring ends."
}
```

With php to write file

```
    <?php

$y = fopen('../autoload.php', 'w');
$x = "<?php class Component {?>";

foreach (glob("*/*.php") as $filename) {
    $x .= fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));
}

$x .= "<?php }";
$x = str_replace('?><?php', '', $x);
$x = str_replace('function ', 'public static function ', $x);
fwrite($y, $x);
```

It seem that good enough but still a hacky way to do thing.

Comment: For the goodness sake, please use **autoload** instead of *that!*

Comment: how can i autoload all function in one class spl_autoload_register just collect class it seem

Comment: Yes! That's the point, exactly. You should load **classes**, not *that*

Answer (score 0):

Pack your functions into classes with static functions.

```
class fctlib{
   public static function fct1(){/*..*/}
   public static function fct2($par){/*..*/}
   //:
}
```

You can use these functions almost as usual. The call is made with classname::functionname().

```
$result = fctlib::fct1();
```

In this way, you can conveniently make your functions available via an autoloader.

Comment: Class should automatically put all function in one class so i dont have to this type any function in a class it will automatically loaded

Comment: This task can only be solved in a special case. All PHP files found must contain exactly one function and the function name must also be identifiable from the file name.

Comment: Can't understand that i just make my component with powershell may be get some answer in future that is better